# Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'listViewStyle'

Tags: android, listview, themes

I am trying to theme my default listview theme.
I have read a lot of stuff on the web and they are all saying this should work:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="textColor">@color/darkblue</item>
    <item name="listViewStyle">@style/MyListViewTheme</item>
</style>
```

with this theme for the ListView:

```
<style name="MyListViewTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkblue</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
</style>
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'listViewStyle'.
```

I really don't understand why I cannot use listViewStyle attribute.

Source:

http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/

http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-2/data/res/values/themes.xml.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel so stupid!

```
<item name="android:listViewStyle">
```

instead of

```
<item name="listViewStyle">
```