# error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'

Tags: android, themes

[Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'listViewStyle'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193172/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-listviewstyle)

I have tried everything from here. Nothing is working.

I have imported API demos to the eclipse of API version 15 and also giving error in src files like "The import com.example.android.apis.R cannot be resolved"

Help me out please.

I have error wit this in `values-v11/styles.xml` file

```
<style name="ThemeHolo" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
</style>

<!-- For API level 11 or later, the Holo theme is available and we prefer that. -->
<style name="ThemeHoloDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
</style>

<!-- For API level 11 or later, we can use the magical DialogWhenLarge theme. -->
<style name="ThemeDialogWhenLarge" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.DialogWhenLarge">
</style>
```

and also I have an error in values/styles.xml "error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar'." in following lines

```
<style name="BadTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'android:Theme.Material.Light'   in     <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light"></style>  in valules-v21 in android studio

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can refer to the Holo theme as `parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"`, but to use the Holo Theme you have to set the build target in your manifest to API level 11 or later, also you have to put the `style.xml` file containing the Holo theme to the folder `values-v11`

Comment: not workin..:( error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/
 Theme.Holo'.

Comment: Did you set the build target correctly in your manifest, and do you have the Android 3.0 or a later API installed in your SDK?

Comment: ya, i hav just installed 4.0.3 api version 15 n imported corresponding sample api demos. and version all set correctly in manifest file

Comment: In eclipse right click on your project, Properties -> Android, and set the project build target ot 4.0.3, when the project recompiles, you should be able to use the Theme. You see it is not enough to set the target in the manifest, you have to tell eclipse to build and validate the project against that API level.

Comment: @AdamL.Mónos,  
 
Cannot resolve symbol 'android:Theme.Material.Light' in <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light"></style> in valules-v21

Comment: Your style declaration should look like this:
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light"></style>

It's in the official "Using the Material theme" page:

Comment: Your style declaration should look like this:
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light"></style>

It's in the official "Using the Material theme" page: https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

Answer (score 20):

Just delete the HOLO as this resource is not available for that API Level

```
        parent="android:Theme.Light"
```

Comment: still having errors in this<style name="ThemeHoloDialog" parent="android:Theme.Light.Dialog">
    </style>

    <!-- For API level 11 or later, we can use the magical DialogWhenLarge theme. -->
    <style name="ThemeDialogWhenLarge" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.DialogWhenLarge">
    </style>

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'android:Theme.Material.Light' in <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light"></style> in valules-v21

Answer (score 3):

Changing the manifest's *android:targetSdkVersion* value to the correct version solved it for me.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'android:Theme.Material.Light' in <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light"></style> in valules-v21

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue even with the correct settings in Properties etc. It seems a problem with Eclipse. I have removed the content of the xml files, then "save", then enter again the values i.e.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

and "save" again.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'android:Theme.Material.Light' in <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light"></style> in valules-v21

Answer (score 0):

Have your written exactly this?

```
<item name="android:listViewStyle">
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by adding

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

within application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file. This will recognize the app theme.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:debuggable="true" > 
        <activity 
            ...
        </activity>
      ...
</application>
```