# AppCompat problems

Tags: android, android-appcompat

SOLVED: Redownloaded supportlibrary, reimported and everyting worked... Why? How? Ask the ghost in the machine! This is a new install of eclipse and the sdk so maybe something has gone wrong from the get-go..

I'm developing an app that where i want to use `android-support-v7-appcompat` and I've imported it as mentioned in Support Library Setup. But when this is done, I get error in `/res/values-v11` and `/res/values-v14` in the files `styles_base.xml` and `themes_base.xml`. All within this support library

All errors in `styles_base.xml` looks like this

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name     android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
```

and the errors in themes_base.xml looks like this:

```
 Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name     'android:Theme.Holo'.
```

and

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
```

`MinSDKVersion` in `appCompat` is 7 and `targetSDK` is 20.

I've removed and re-imported a couple of times without success. When I look at the buildpath, I get an error saying that `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` is missing from `\android-support-v7-appcomapt\libs`...

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295018/error-error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-give